# Django/Python - Unable to decode FILE Upload

Tags: python, django, decode, encode

I'm working with Django v1.11 and Python.  I'm attempting to upload a file and then parse it.  The file has some odd encoding, so I initial wrote a test script and discovered the file was using utf-16 encoding.  With that test script (which I used outside of Django) I used:

```
inputFile = open(inputFilePath, 'rt', encoding='utf-16')
```

When using Django, I am having trouble doing the decoding. In my views.py I use:

```
if "specFile" in request.FILES: 
    specFilePath = request.FILES['specFile']
    if(request.POST['specType'] == 'Absorbance'): 
        doStuff(specFilePath)
```

Which goes to the simple method:

```
def doStuff(specFilePath):
    for line in specFilePath:
        print(line)
```

Here I get encoded text:

```
b'\xff\xfe#\x00#\x00B\x00L\x00O\x00C\x00K\x00S\x00=\x00 \x006\x00\r'
b'\x00\n'
b'\x00P\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00\t\x00e\x001\x00\t\x001\x00.\x003\x00\t\x00P\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00F\x00o\x00r\x00m\x00a\x00t\x00\t\x00E\x00n\x00d\x00p\x00o\x00i\x00n\x00t\x00\t\x00A\x00b\x00s\x00o\x00r\x00b\x00a\x00n\x00c\x00e\x00\t\x00R\x00a\x00w\x00\t\x00F\x00A\x00L\x00S\x00E\x00\t\x001\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x002\x00\t\x002\x006\x000\x00 \x002\x008\x000\x00 \x00\t\x001\x00\t\x002\x004\x00\t\x003\x008\x004\x00\t\x001\x00\t\x001\x006\x00\t\x00\t\x00\r'
    ...

When putting in  
    line = line.decode(encoding='latin1')

b'\xff\xfe#\x00#\x00B\x00L\x00O\x00C\x00K\x00S\x00=\x00 \x006\x00\r'
b'\x00\n'
b'\x00P\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00:\x00\t\x00e\x001\x00\t\x001\x00.\x003\x00\t\x00P\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00F\x00o\x00r\x00m\x00a\x00t\x00\t\x00E\x00n\x00d\x00p\x00o\x00i\x00n\x00t\x00\t\x00A\x00b\x00s\x00o\x00r\x00b\x00a\x00n\x00c\x00e\x00\t\x00R\x00a\x00w\x00\t\x00F\x00A\x00L\x00S\x00E\x00\t\x001\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x002\x00\t\x002\x006\x000\x00 \x002\x008\x000\x00 \x00\t\x001\x00\t\x002\x004\x00\t\x003\x008\x004\x00\t\x001\x00\t\x001\x006\x00\t\x00\t\x00\r'
...
```

---

When putting in

```
line = line.decode(encoding='utf-16')
```

I get the error message:
UnicodeDecodeError: `'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x0d in position 24: truncated data`

I'm not sure where to go from here.  Is there some other way to do the decoding?
Also, apologies for any errors or poor phrasing in this question.  This is my first Stack Overflow question ever asked and Django/Python are just tools I use in my work in the scientific side of Drug Discovery platform development.

Comment: Whatever is splitting your file into lines is unaware that it's in UTF16, and is splitting it on a single-byte character that isn't even meaningful here.  You need to somehow get Django to consider the file to be UTF16 before the line splitting; sorry, that's a bit outside my experience.

Comment: how did you find that is encoded in `utf-16` ?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a rather janky solution that seems to work:

```
line = line.strip().replace('\xff', '').replace('\xfe', '').replace('\x00', '').rstrip()
```

This seems to do the trick by eliminating the \xff type stuff.
And for reference and easy googling, these problems arose from the data file from a Molecular Devices Spectromax absorbance / fluorscence plate reader.